# Will increasing my water line to 1 into and throughout my house from 3/4 in increase my water pressure from 120 ft after meter

Tags: water-pressure

I'm adding a new valve and connection for a outdoor water hose in the front of my house for my family to use and benefit from. I'm roughly 120 ft from the meter where a 3/4in line connects to my house. I want to increase the line to 1 in from that connection point through the 3 connection points I have following the connection to my house. Basically if I put a 1 in line for 20 ft with T at 13 ft into another T 7 ft later that will have a 8in stub to a 90 adapter 3/4 threaded to 1 PVC then 10 ft 3/4 to valve on one side then a 18 in stub down to another 90 adapter 3/4 threaded to 1 in. PVC then 35ft 3/4 pipe to 90 to 36 in pipe to 90 to 8in stub to valve. Doing so would it make a difference in the water pressure or just a waste of time and money?

Comment: It should reduce friction/turbulance resistance, and thus reduce pressure loss from those dynamic causes. How much, I have no clue.

Comment: You'll be waiting twice as long for hot water, if you use it on the hot pipes.

Comment: Not going to be worth it unless you replace the 120' of 3/4 too

Answer (score 2):

At no flow, it will make no difference. A pipe of 1/8" and a pipe of 6" have exactly the same pressure (if connected to the same endpoints) with zero flow. So if the pressure in the house now with no water running is, say, 43.2 PSI, that won't change.

At any other flow, it will make some difference. How much, you can figure out using a **dynamic head calculator** for your collection of pipe and fittings, and flow rates representing your uses. The greater the flow, the greater the difference. Essentially, you're going to be limited by the 120 ft of 3/4, but losses *after* that can be reduced. If you want significantly more pressure at flow you'd need to replace that 120 foot line with larger pipe.